# Totally bounded set in the space of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

I have a set $$S  = \{ f \in C^2 [0,1] : \| f\|_c + \|f''\| = 1\}$$ in space $(C^2 [0,1], \| \cdot \|)$, where $\| f(x) \|_c = \max\limits_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)|$.

So to check that this space in totally bounded, I want to use Arzelà–Ascoli theorem, for that I need boundness, which is obvious because $\|f\|_c \le \|f\|_c + \|f'' \| = 1$, but I have problem with uniformly equicontinuous. I have to check follow condition
$$ \forall \varepsilon > 0 ~ \exists \delta > 0 : \forall f \in S ~ \forall x_1, x_2 :|x_1 - x_2| < \delta \hookrightarrow | f(x_1) - f(x_2)| < \varepsilon. $$

I tried to use mean value and Weierstrass theorems, but I from these I got $$|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| = |f'(\xi)||x_1 - x_2| < \varepsilon$$
with $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{ \max\limits_{x \in [0,1]} |f'(x)|} $ depends on function, which I don't want.

So what I'm missing when trying to pick up the value of $\delta$ not depending on function?

Comment: What does $ \| \cdot \|$ stand for in $(C^2 [0,1], \| \cdot \|)$ ?

Comment: The standard norm in $C^2[0,1]$ is $|\max|f(x)|\in[0,1]$ + $\max|f'(x)|\in[0,1]$ + $\max|f''(x)|\in[0,1]$, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\|f\|_\infty+ \|f''\|_\infty \le 1$. By Taylor's Theorem
$$
f(1)=f(0)+f'(0)\cdot 1+\frac{1}{2}f''(\xi)\cdot 1^2
$$
for some $\xi \in (0,1)$. Hence
$$
|f'(0)| \le |f(1)| + |f(0)| + \frac{1}{2}|f''(\xi)| \le \frac{5}{2}.
$$
Now for $x \in [0,1]$
$$
|f'(x)| = |f'(0) + \int_0^x f''(t)dt| \le |f'(0)| + \int_0^x |f''(t)|dt \le \frac{5}{2} + \int_0^1 1 dt = \frac{7}{2}.
$$
Thus each $f \in S$ is Lipschitz with constant $7/2$.